# Magento: Show left category nav on sub-sub-sub category page

Tags: php, magento

I am working with a Magento Porto theme and need the left-side category navigation (category_nav.html) to show on sub-sub-sub category pages. I managed to get it to show up on sub-sub category pages, but can't figure out how to get passed there.

Here is my current code:

```
    <?php
        $_categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('level', 2)
            ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1);
    ?>

    <?php $_count = is_array($_categories)?count($_categories):$_categories->count(); ?>
    <?php
        function cmpCatPosition($a, $b) {
            if ($a->position == $b->position)
                return 0;
            return ($a->position > $b->position) ? 1 : -1;
        }
        function getChildrenCategoriesHtml($_category){
            $children = explode( ",", $_category->getChildren() );
            //usort($children, 'cmpCatPosition');
            $content = '';
            $content .= '<li class="';
            if(!$children[0])
                $content .= 'has-no-children';
            else
                $content .= 'has-children';
            $content .= '">';
            $content .= '<a href="'.$_category->getUrl().'" ';
            $content .= '>'.$_category->getName().'</a>';
            if($children[0]){
                $content .= '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="plus"><i class="icon-plus-squared"></i></a>';
                $content .= '<ul>';
                foreach($children as $child){
                    $_subcat = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/category' )->load( $child );
                    $content .= getChildrenCategoriesHtml($_subcat);
                }
                $content .= '</ul>';
            }
            $content .= '</li>';
            return $content;
        }
    ?>
    <?php if($_count): ?>
    <div class="block block-category-nav">
        <div class="block-title">
            <strong><span><?php echo Mage::registry('current_category')->getName(); ?></span></strong>
        </div>
        <div class="block-content">
            <ul class="category-list">
            <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
                <?php
                if($_category->getIsActive()){
                    echo getChildrenCategoriesHtml($_category);
                }
                ?>
            <?php endforeach ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Example on how we can reproduce this with pure PHP would be nice, otherwise it is "do it for me".

Comment: I assume it has something to do with the filtering at the very top of the code I posted. I'm not asking for anyone to do anything for me. Just show me what I am missing. The majority of this code isn't even necessary for the function that I am trying to accomplish. I just added it so someone could get the full scope.

Answer (score 0):

The code that I made actually works. I just missed adding "Is Anchor -> Yes" in the back end.

There is a code where this can be done globally, but I want control over what shows and what does not, so selecting Yes/No on the anchor solves the issue.

This was (after all the pulling my hair out trying to make it work) not a programming issue.